# How to constrain Filebeat to only ship logs to ELK if they contain a specific field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, filebeat

I’m trying to collect logs from Kubernetes nodes using Filebeat and ONLY ship them to ELK IF the logs originate from a specific Kubernetes Namespace.

So far I’ve discovered that you can define *Processors* which I think accomplish this. However, no matter what I do I can not get the shipped logs to be constrained. Does this look right?

Hm, does this look correct then?

```
filebeat.config:
  inputs:
    path: ${path.config}/inputs.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: true
    reload.period: 10s
    when.contains:
      kubernetes.namespace: "NAMESPACE"
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false
  processors:
    - add_kubernetes_metadata:
      namespace: "NAMESPACE"
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ['elasticsearch:9200']
```

Despite this configuration I still get logs from all of the namespaces.

Filebeat is running as a DaemonSet on Kubernetes. Here is an example of an expanded log entry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWMqF.png

Comment: Did you check the drop filter? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filtering-and-enhancing-data.html

Comment: No, but this is a good idea. Would I specify a regular expression that says drop all events when they don't match the specific namespace? How would that be structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I resolved this by moving the drop processor to the input configuration file from the configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

You have number options to do it:

1. [Filter data by filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filtering-and-enhancing-data.html)

```
processors:
 - drop_event:
     when:
        contains:
           source: "field"
```

2. [Use ingest pipeline into elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-ingest-node.html):

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  pipeline: my_pipeline_id
```

And then test events into [pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/drop-processor.html):

```
{
  "drop": {
    "if" : "ctx['field'] == null "
  }
}
```

3. [Use drop filter of logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html):

```
filter {
  if ![field] {
    drop { }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried many variations of the first option you listed. In the end, I resolved this by moving the drop processor to the input configuration file from the configuration file.